# How to ensure that a particular column is counted only once in Group BY

Tags: mysql

I have the below MySQL table containing the below data:

```
MariaDB [testdb]> select * from courses;
+---------+---------+
| student | class   |
+---------+---------+
| A       | Math    |
| B       | English |
| C       | Math    |
| D       | Biology |
| E       | Math    |
| F       | Math    |
| A       | Math    |
+---------+---------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now i have a simple case scenario in which i want to see the count of people attending a particular class. So i used this query , giving me the below result:

```
   MariaDB [testdb]> select class, count(class) from courses group by class;
+---------+--------------+
| class   | count(class) |
+---------+--------------+
| Biology |            1 |
| English |            1 |
| Math    |            5 |
+---------+--------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

But the catch here is that it is counting the row with Student = 'A' for class = 'Math' twice.

When we are doing a count i have to ensure that each student is accounted for only once.

How can i modify the above query to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: See COUNT(DISTINCT ...), but you really need a PRIMARY KEY here. And be careful about what you're counting, and what you're grouping.

Comment: Read about [`COUNT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) function. It accepts the `DISTINCT` modifier.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I can't help but think that perhaps the problem lies in the data itself.  Why should student A be listed twice?  Is this not an error?  If it isn't, why wouldn't you count it twice?  Something doesn't fit here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query

```
SELECT temp.class,count(temp.class) FROM(
select student,class from courses group by student
) AS temp 
GROUP BY `class`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DISTINCT`, e.g.:

```
SELECT class, COUNT(DISTINCT(student))
FROM courses
GROUP BY class;
```

This should give you de-deuped counts.

Alternatively, you can also group by class and student to get count per class per student e.g.:

```
SELECT class, student, COUNT(*)
FROM courses
GROUP BY class, student;
```